# Error with Date format in PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm having problems with the handling of a date format.
In my code, I try to calculate an expiration date starting from a specified date and then to save it in my MySQL database.

The problem is that I always receive this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object

and I'm not able to solve it.
For example, it works if I manually replace $scadenza_contratto with a specific date, for example:

```
$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-02-10');
```

In this case, it works, but I need to receive date from $scadenza_contratto.
Can you help me, please?
This is my code:

```
if($anno > 0 && $giorno > 0 && $mese >0){
$scadenza_contratto = $anno."-".$mese."-".$giorno;
//$scadenza_contratto = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+{$scadenze} months", strtotime($scadenza_contratto)));

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM scadenze WHERE contratto_id=$contratti_id";

$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query($sql1) );
echo "tipo ".$row1['tipo'];

 if(!$row1){

 for ($m = $scadenze; $m <=60 ; $m += $scadenze){
   //add $m to activation_date
   $scadenza_contratto = $anno."-".$mese."-".$giorno;
   $expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$scadenza_contratto');
   $expiration_date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$m.'M'));
   //do something with $expriration_date 
   echo "Expire: ".$expiration_date->format('Y-m-d'). "<br>";
   $expiration_db = $expiration_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $time=time();

//mysql_query("INSERT INTO contratti (nome_area) VALUES('$nome_area','$giorno','$mese','$file_name','$attiva','$id_voce','$nome_azienda','$time')");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO scadenze (nome_azienda,nome_voce,contratto_id,nome_area,scadenza,tipo,created_date) VALUES ('$nome_azienda','$nome_voce','$contratti_id','$nome_area','$expiration_db','$scadenze','$time')");

  } 

 }
}
```

Comment: echo `$scadenza_contratto` before to use in `$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$scadenza_contratto');`

Comment: If `$mese` or `$giorno` have values less than 10 (which is quite possible as you're treating them as integer values rather than as two-character strings), then your format mask will need to be `'Y-n-j'` rather than `'Y-m-d'`

Comment: I  tried to change Y-m-d in Y-n-j but it still gives that error.

Comment: However, you also don't want to use quotes around `$scadenza_contratto`; (`$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$scadenza_contratto');` as this will treat it as a string literal.... you're trying to convert the string literal `'$scadenza_contratto'` to a date, rather than the value of the string variable `$scadenza_contratto`

Comment: If I echo $scadenza_contratto I read " 2016 -2-2" and so there is a space. Do you think this can be the problem?

Comment: A space will also cause a problem, because it won't match the mask.... so trim your year value to eliminate that space.... `$anno = trim($anno);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

```
$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '$scadenza_contratto');
```

You're trying to convert the string literal `'$scadenza_contratto'` to a date, rather than the value of the string variable `$scadenza_contratto`.

A second problem is your format mask, as you're treating the values of `$mese` and `$giorno` as integers, then they may have values less than 10; and your current mask assumes that they will always be two digit values (with a leading `0` if less than 10), which may not be the case

Change this to

```
$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $scadenza_contratto);
```

Comment: So, it should be: '$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "$scadenza_contratto");' ?

Comment: Don't put any quotes around variables; there's no need..... do you see quotes around `$scadenza_contratto` in my answer?

Comment: Thank guys, now it works. There was also another problem: there was a space in $anno.